# How to unescape % in LIKE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have my search patterns stored in database in `patterns` table. For example my table column `name_pattern` contains string 'Basic%'. I'd like to create dynamic search where search patterns will be fetched from `name_pattern` column.

So my SQL query should look something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE product_name LIKE name_pattern <-- somehow joined from patterns table
```

Seems that Oracle escapes % in my string but I want to take it unescapped in order my query to work like:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE product_name LIKE 'Basic%'
```

I found that my problem is with stable set of rows:

```
CREATE TABLE patterns(code CHAR(1),name_pattern VARCHAR2(20));
INSERT INTO patterns(code,name_pattern) VALUES('B','Basic%');
INSERT INTO patterns(code,name_pattern) VALUES('T','%thing');

CREATE TABLE products (id NUMBER,name VARCHAR2(20),code CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO products(id,name,found) VALUES(1,'Basic instinct',NULL);
INSERT INTO products(id,name,found) VALUES(2,'Basic thing',NULL);
INSERT INTO products(id,name,found) VALUES(3,'Super thing',NULL);
INSERT INTO products(id,name,found) VALUES(4,'Hyper instinct',NULL);

MERGE INTO products p USING
(
   SELECT code,name_pattern FROM patterns
) s
ON (p.name LIKE s.name_pattern)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET p.code=s.code;

SELECT * FROM products;
```

If my search patterns were `Basic%` and `Super%` in patterns table then this MERGE will work, but if my search patterns are `Basic%` and `%thing`, the second product should be marked with both codes 'B' and 'T' and that causes the error:

```
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
```

So my problem is not in (un)escaping :-(, sorry

Comment: As I know you can escape it with `%%`

Comment: If your name_pattern contains `'Basic%'`, then `LIKE name_pattern ` is equal to `LIKE 'Basic%'`. https://dbfiddle.uk/nviXiJzQ

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain why you think it is escaping it - maybe show sample data and the behaviour you're seeing? (i.e. a [mre].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to (un)escape anything, I'd say.

```
SQL> with
  2  patterns (name_pattern) as
  3    (select 'Basic%'    from dual union all
  4     select '%foot%'    from dual
  5    ),
  6  products (id, name) as
  7    (select 1, 'Basic instinct' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'Visual Basic'   from dual union all
  9     select 3, 'Littlefoot'     from dual union all
 10     select 4, 'Happy feet'     from dual
 11    )
 12  select b.id, b.name, a.name_pattern
 13  from products b join patterns a on b.name like a.name_pattern;

        ID NAME           NAME_P
---------- -------------- ------
         1 Basic instinct Basic%
         3 Littlefoot     %foot%

SQL>
```

---

Based on test case you provided: don't merge, update!

```
SQL> update products p set
  2    p.found = 1
  3    where exists (select null
  4                  from patterns o
  5                  where p.name like o.name_pattern
  6                 );

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from products;

        ID NAME                      FOUND
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Basic instinct                1
         2 Basic thing                   1
         3 Super thing                   1
         4 Hyper instinct                0

SQL>
```

---

After you changed your mind (again), it is still `update`. Though, you didn't explain *which code* you want to take when there's multiple match (for example, product 2 matches both "Basic%" and "%thing") so I took *any* of them, using the `min` function.

```
SQL> update products p set
  2    p.code = (select min(o.code)
  3              from patterns o
  4              where p.name like o.name_pattern
  5             );

4 rows updated.

SQL> select * from products;

        ID NAME                 CODE
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Basic instinct       B
         2 Basic thing          B
         3 Super thing          T
         4 Hyper instinct       NULL

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I don't need to (un)escape anything, my problem was with multiple update found by more than one search pattern. I will update my OP.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot a lot, I updated my OP as well, I need not just "1" as stated before but search marker (code) from patterns table, and  cannot transfer it (ambiguity occurs, order of patterns does not apply where and mark ill update over previous one.)

Comment: Ha ha, legend, reducing (somehow) records to one! That helps. Thanks